# Clone OSX and Windows bootcamp to SSD from HDD

Tags: ssd, boot-camp, clone

i'm in desperate need of help

my state -Installed ssd into machine (optical drive slot) - erased ssd

Now i want to clone everything thats on my hard drive to my sdd. I started up carbon copy cloner and then realised i can only clone MAC OSX or the bootcamp. Not both!

Does anyone know what the best approach is to clone the entire hard drive to ssd including both MAX OSX and window bootcamp paritions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, [Paragon Hard Disk Manager](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hdm-mac/) is the only app that can do this task.

[TwoCanoe's WinClone](https://twocanoes.com/products/mac/winclone) can do the Boot Camp partition, but doesn't handle the Mac partitions.

Paragon is the more expensive, but you can occasionally find it in these online bundle deals. I got mine for about 15 bucks, along with a whole bunch of other stuff I didn't need & in exchange they spam me 4 times a year with what else they have on offer.
Personally, I call that a fair swap ;-)

CCC is great for your Mac Partitions, but not Boot Camp. It requires you already have the specialised partitioning structure in place - see Bombich KB: [Can CCC back up my BootCamp (Windows) partition?](https://bombich.com/kb/ccc4/can-ccc-back-up-my-bootcamp-windows-partition)

<sup>I own all three, but am not affiliated with any of the recommendations</sup>

Answer (score 0):

if you are using  linux the 'dd' command should help you.
Cloning disks can be difficult if you are using different drivers, the data is written in cylinders and blocks that can be of different sizes or none existent from one type of drive to another. This will affect the way the data is distributed on the device and how the partitions are made. Try to create partitions of same sizes before cloning (a partition on your sdd = or > in size as the MAC OSX partition and another the size >= as the bootcamp, and treat each partition as if it was a single drive. Another solution would be making image (.iso for example) of the partitions (ps: you cannot boot from a image file, unless it is a virtual machine). i hope this helps

Comment: I would be extremely wary of trying to clone using anything that is not specifically Boot Camp-aware. The GUID/MBR hybrid is so easy to break.